# Lucene.net and 3.5

Tags: lucene.net

Are there any special considerations to be aware of when building a 3.5 application against the 2.0 build for lucene.net?

I found a couple guys would posted their project files for lucene, but wasn't sure if that was the proper way to go.

Answer (score 6):

The Lucene.NET port isn't really .NET. It's truly an exact port of the Java Lucene project. This means things like the search results do not implement IEnumerable<T> and instead implement an ugly Java iterator, objects that need to be Close() don't implement IDisposable, values that should be enums are public fields, other uglies.

Despite all this, we're very happy with Lucene's performance and general configurability. It can do most anything you'd want a search engine to do.

You should also be aware of [Linq-to-Lucene](http://www.codeplex.com/linqtolucene), a .NET 3.5 project that lets you query Lucene using LINQ syntax (as opposed to having to learn domain-specific Lucene query syntax).

Comment: I myself have played with Linq-to-Lucene.  It's nice.  +1 vote

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Lucene.NET in a .NET Framework 3.5 application for a month or so without problems.